# How to dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu Lenovo Y520

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I have a Lenovo Y520 with:

- A 128GB SSD: SAMSUNG MZVLW128HEGR-000L2 with Windows installed on it
- A 500 GB SSD: CT500MX500SSD1 with Data for windows (movies, games)

I would like to install Ubuntu on dual boot mode.
I would like to install Ubuntu on the 500GB SSD.

I made space on the only partition of the 500GB SSD in order to install Ubuntu.
For more details, you can have a look at the disk management menu:
[image]

When trying to install Ubuntu, in the partition step:

1. I created a primary partition, with / as volume mount, in ext4
2. I created another primary partition, used as swap
3. I selected the 128GB SSD as the bootloader installation directory

During my first installation attempt, this end up with the following error: "it was not possible to install the bootloader at the specified location menu stuck"

Could you help me find what is wrong with my configuration?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Is this a UEFI or legacy Windows installation?  Looks like UEFI from the 5 primary partitions on ssd (implying uefi),  but looks like any partition that might be an EFI partition is empty (so no bootloaders). Are you able to boot Windows?  Which is your EFI partition?  If the 100M, it may be too small, 300-500 is the usual recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue!

Actually, I wasn't running the USB key with the EFI partition.
I was always starting it with another name in the UEFI boot device selection menu and I when I selected "EFI USB device", Ubuntu installer started to display "Install alongside Windows".

Ubuntu then created:

1. A main partition
2. An EFI partition
3. A swap partition

Answer (score 1):

Make an EFI partition of 300-500 Mb on the 500 GB Disk.

- Choose the size.
- Make EFI boot partition. During installation mount this as `/boot`.
- Make your Ubuntu partition ( if you are not going to install more
  Linux distributions the SWAP partition has no advantage over the
  (now) standard Swapfile! ). During install mount this as `/`
- If you decide to make a SWAP partition anyway I advice you to make it
  at the end of the disk ( if you ever need to repartition it makes it
  a lot easier ).

With this setup you can choose which disk you want to boot. Boot the small one for Windows and boot the 500 for Ubuntu. If you choose the 500 you will be presented with the Grub menu.

Comment: Thanks for helping me!

Actually, there is no need to move the EFI partition to the beginning of the disk.
UEFI standard does not need this, this was one of the point of this standard.
MBR required the bootloader to be at the beginning of the disk, which is a pain.

Ubuntu created another EFI partition.
By selecting the Ubuntu bootloader on computer start, I am able to select if I want to start Ubuntu or Windows (Thanks to GRUB2).